# python failed to call flash loaded html page

Tags: javascript, python, html, flash

I tried to render html page which contains flash content. But it not responding. Loads endless. Text and image contents are OK. Here is my code.

```
self.response.out.write(template.render('ieerror.html', dict()))
```

html file contains:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>flash content</title>
<script src="scripts/AC_RunActiveContent.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body style=" text-align:center">
<script type="text/javascript">
AC_FL_RunContent( 'codebase','http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0','width','740','height','473','title','image navigation','src','image_navigation','quality','high','pluginspage','http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash','movie','image_navigation' ); //end AC code
</script><noscript><object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0" width="740" height="473" title="image navigation">
  <param name="movie" value="image_navigation.swf" />
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <embed src="image_navigation.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="740" height="473"></embed>
</object></noscript>
</body>
```

Comment: What does this mean? How are you "rendering" this page? What is `self.response`?

Answer (score 0):

Use http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/ instead

like [from](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var flashvars = false;
var params = {
  menu: "false",
  flashvars: "name1=hello&name2=world&name3=foobar"
};
var attributes = {
  id: "myDynamicContent",
  name: "myDynamicContent"
};

swfobject.embedSWF("myContent.swf", "myContent", "300", "120", "9.0.0","expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);

</script>
```

and yes, except this code `self.response.out.write(template.render('ieerror.html', dict()))` we **NEED** all other runnable sample from your *Python* code.

Thanks!